# Resistor tolerance has 1% given in the datasheet. Does it include all (aging, temperature co-efficient and manufacture )

Tags: circuit-analysis

Resistor tolerance has 1% given in the datasheet. Does it include all (ageing, temperature co-efficient, solder joint and manufacturer tolerance.)

For my worst case can I consider 1% alone? Does it include all the error influences of the resistor?

Comment: What does the datasheet say? Usually they are pretty specific about the test conditions for each specification (though you may not have access to the standard).

Comment: [The Photon](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/488469/38098) has some comments on this. Worth a read.

Comment: If you read the datahset carefully, you'll probably find it described as 'initial tolerance'. You have to add ageing and tempco on top of that. Link to the datasheet.

Comment: Normally just manufacturing, temperature comes on top of that.

Comment: Read the complete datasheet very carefully. Look for application notes from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Resistor tolerance only refers to the initial nominal value.

All other effects are either unspecified or specified separately. Typically, basic "non-precision" resistors will only specify maximum tempco, in ppm/C. Resistors targeted for precision applications will also specify the curvature of the tempco, voltage coefficient of resistance, aging, etc.